# ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Tags: bash, postgresql, subquery, expression

I have searched and searched.. I have a bash script that is used to run a psql query and email the results on a daily basis. The DB does not update till midnight and my bash script passes a variable to the query for the day prior. I am getting this error only when I use the passed variable otherwise if I put the date in the query manually it runs fine. Not quite sure for I am still learning psql and bash.

Here is the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
NOWDATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d -d "yesterday"`
SUBDATE=`date '+%B %e, %G'`
DIR=/file/report/
FILE=file-$NOWDATE.csv
RECIPIENT=email@mail.com

PGPASSWORD=passwrod psql -w -h host -p 5432 -d database -U user -o $DIR/$FILE <<EOF
select distinct als."Table_AccountID",
   (select  "Table_val_AccountStatusID" from  "Table_log_AccountStatus"  
    where "Table_AccountID" = als."Table_AccountID" order by  "Date" desc limit 1)
    as "Table_val_AccountStatusID",

   CASE  
   when (select count(*) from  "Table_UsageHistory"  cfuh  
         where cfuh."Disk">'123456' and date_trunc('day',cfuh."Created") = date_trunc('day','$NOWDATE'::timestamp)
         -- -'1day':: interval
         and extrTable('day' from "Created"::timestamp) = ac."DesiredBillingDate" 
         and date_trunc('day', "Created"::timestamp) = date_trunc('day', '$NOWDATE'::timestamp)
         and cfuh."Table_AccountID" in (
             select distinct "Table_AccountID" from "Table_Usage" 
             where date_trunc('day', "Timestamp"::timestamp) = date_trunc('day','$NOWDATE'::timestamp)
             and "Table_AccountID" = cfuh."Table_AccountID")
         and cfuh."Table_AccountID" = als."Table_AccountID") >0
   then 'Y'
   else 'N'
   end as "RollUp",

   (select distinct bc."ID" from "BIL_BillableCharge" bc, "Table_UsageHistory" cfh 
    where date_trunc('day',bc."Date"::timestamp) = date_trunc('day',cfh."Created"::timestamp)
    and bc."Table_AccountID" = cfh."Table_AccountID" and bc."BIL_val_InvoiceItemTypeID" = '23' 
    and extrTable('month' from "Created"::timestamp) = extrTable('month' from '$NOWDATE'::timestamp)
    and  extrTable('year' from "Created"::timestamp) = extrTable('year' from '$NOWDATE'::timestamp)
    and cfh."Table_AccountID" = als."Table_AccountID") as "BillableChargeID"

    from "Table_log_AccountStatus" als, "Table_Account" ac
    group by als."Table_AccountID",  ac."ID", ac."DesiredBillingDate"
    having (select distinct "Disk" from "Table_UsageHistory" cfu
    where  date_trunc('day', cfu."Created") = date_trunc('day','$NOWDATE'::timestamp)
    and ac."ID" = cfu."Table_AccountID")>'123456'
    and extrTable('day' from '$NOWDATE'::timestamp) = ac."DesiredBillingDate"
    and ac."ID" = als."Table_AccountID"
    ORDER BY "RollUp" ASC
EOF

sed -i '2d' $DIR/$FILE |
   mailx -a $DIR/$FILE -s " Report for $SUBDATE" -r email@anotheremail.com $RECIPIENT
```

Here's the SQL, reformatted for readability.

```
select distinct 
  als."Table_AccountID",

  (select  "Table_val_AccountStatusID" 
   from  "Table_log_AccountStatus"  
   where "Table_AccountID" = als."Table_AccountID" 
   order by  "Date" desc limit 1) as "Table_val_AccountStatusID",

   CASE when 
        (select count(*) 
         from  "Table_UsageHistory"  cfuh  
         where  cfuh."Disk">'123456' 
           and date_trunc('day',cfuh."Created") = date_trunc('day','$NOWDATE'::timestamp) -- -'1day':: interval
           and extrTable('day' from "Created"::timestamp) = ac."DesiredBillingDate" 
           and date_trunc('day', "Created"::timestamp) = date_trunc('day', '$NOWDATE'::timestamp)
           and cfuh."Table_AccountID" in 
              (select distinct "Table_AccountID" 
               from "Table_Usage" 
               where date_trunc('day', "Timestamp"::timestamp) = date_trunc('day','$NOWDATE'::timestamp)
                 and "Table_AccountID" = cfuh."Table_AccountID")
                 and cfuh."Table_AccountID" = als."Table_AccountID") > 0
        then 'Y'
        else 'N'
   end as "RollUp",

  (select distinct bc."ID" 
   from "BIL_BillableCharge" bc, "Table_UsageHistory" cfh 
   where date_trunc('day',bc."Date"::timestamp) = date_trunc('day',cfh."Created"::timestamp)
     and bc."Table_AccountID" = cfh."Table_AccountID" and bc."BIL_val_InvoiceItemTypeID" = '23' 
     and extrTable('month' from "Created"::timestamp) = extrTable('month' from '$NOWDATE'::timestamp)
     and  extrTable('year' from "Created"::timestamp) = extrTable('year' from '$NOWDATE'::timestamp)
     and cfh."Table_AccountID" = als."Table_AccountID") as "BillableChargeID"

from "Table_log_AccountStatus" als, "Table_Account" ac
group by als."Table_AccountID",  ac."ID", ac."DesiredBillingDate"
having (select distinct "Disk" 
        from "Table_UsageHistory" cfu  
        where  date_trunc('day', cfu."Created") = date_trunc('day','$NOWDATE'::timestamp)
          and ac."ID" = cfu."Table_AccountID")>'123456'  
   and extrTable('day' from '$NOWDATE'::timestamp) = ac."DesiredBillingDate" 
   and ac."ID" = als."Table_AccountID"
 ORDER BY "RollUp" ASC
```

When ran just like this from command line on the server it spits out the error:
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

I appreciate the help, this community is the best.. Sorry for the formatting, it came from the copy paste.

Comment: What makes you think that `select distinct bc."ID" from "BIL_BillableCharge" bc, ...` will result in exactly one value? You might want to switch to explicit JOIN conditions as well.

Comment: Your date arithmetic is commented out. Is that part of the problem?

Comment: @muistooshort: I think the only other subquery that might not return a single values is `select distinct "Disk"...`.

Comment: @Catcall: Right, that one could be problematic as well. I missed that one in all the quotes and subqueries. The rest appear to be covered by `IN` or `LIMIT`, right?

Comment: Well it was none-of-the-above... WTF Over... has something to do with the Year.  When I put a date in for 2011. it works if I put it in for 2012 I get that error...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a subquery in the SELECT part, e.g., (`SELECT a, b, (SELECT c from d ...)`) of a query is used then this must return **one** value. An error is returned because one the subqueries returns **more than one row**. Check all the subqueries to ensure that these do not return more than one row. Add a `LIMIT 1` clause if it is acceptable that more than one value exists, but only one is taken.

Comment: Is there a way to append "more than one row" to the other query?